# React Native useState value not changing

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I have a problem in making app with react native.

I use useState, but its value is not updated and the component is not re-rendered.

This is my code.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

function MyScreen({route}) {
    var dateString = route.params;
    const [JsonValue, setJsonValue] = useState([]);

    
    const readData = async (day) => {
         //Code to load data from AsyncStorage
         //get [{character: "A", bool: false}]
         const ReadValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(dateString);
         const data = ReadValue != null ? JSON.parse(ReadValue) : null;
         setJsonValue(data);
     }

    useEffect(() => {
        readData(dateString);
    }, [JsonValue])


    return(
        <View>
            {JsonValue.map((_item, key) => (
               <View key={key}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                     var loopvar = 0;
                     for (const itemitem of JsonValue) {
                         if (itemitem.character == _item.character) {
                             var item = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(itemitem));
                             item.bool = false;
                             var itemall = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JsonValue));
                             itemall[loopvar] = item;
                             setJsonValue(itemall);
                             break;
                         }
                     loopvar += 1;
                     }
                  }}>
                  <Image
                     source={require('./assets/checkbox.png')}
                  />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
               </View>
            ))}
        </View>
    );
}
```

The problem comes from `setJsonValue(itemall);`

After the code runs, it doesn't render and the values ​​don't change.

Before running `setJsonValue(itemall);`, the value of JsonValue was [{character: "A", bool: false}] and the value of itemall was [{character: "A", bool: true}].

Can you solve this problem? If so, please give me an answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the `item` you are using in if statement is conflicting with the scoped `item` inside the if block and hence item will always be `undefined` and hence `item.character` will throw error. Also as you mentioned in your question that you want the `bool` to be `true` in `itemall` but in your code you are setting it to `false` which won't change the apparent value of `JsonValue` because it was already `false` but state will update though.

Here try with below code, it is working for me. State is updating and re-render  is also working.

UPDATE: Remove `JsonValue` from `useEffect` dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
        readData(dateString);
}, [])//remove JsonValue from this array

return(
        <View>
            {JsonValue.map((__item, key) => (
               <View key={key}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                     var loopvar = 0;
                     for (const itemitem of JsonValue) {
                         if (itemitem.character == __item.character) {
                             var item = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(itemitem));
                             item.bool = true;//make it true
                             var itemall = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JsonValue));
                             itemall[loopvar] = item;
                             setJsonValue(itemall);
                             break;
                         }
                     loopvar += 1;
                     }
                  }}>
                  <Image
                     source={require('./assets/checkbox.png')}
                  />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
               </View>
            ))}
            {/*Added this text to check if re-render is working*/}
            <Text>{JsonValue[0]?.bool ? "True" : "False"}</Text>
        </View>
);
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks but that didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I've modified the code in the question based on your comments.

Comment: You are running useEffect on Jsonvalue state change and I think the value of dateString is same and hence getting the same data from async storage which you got when the component mounted. Try removing it from useEffect dependency array.

Comment: Surprisingly it worked! Thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer with above changes. Please upvote and accept the answer to help others who are facing the same issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing may be because of the quality comparison operator `itemitem.character = __item.character`

To compare the values you should use the triple equal sign `===` operator or double equals sign `==`

So it will be `if (itemitem.character === __item.character)`

Let me know if this works :)

Comment: It didn't solve the problem, but it allowed us to improve the code.And I'll also fix the code in the question.Thanks.